# Working with Dates and Querys

Tags: android, sqlite, date, android-sqlite

I'm new to Android programming and working on a first, small App.

I implemented an SQLite Database with 3 Columns (`KEY_ID`,`KEY_DATUM`,`KEY_ANZAHL`), where the Date Column is a String in the Format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Where I struggle is getting Data out with a Query.

Can someone help me set up a Query, which checks if there is already a certain Date in my Database, and the either Add a new Entry in the DB or update an existing one? I also read about the `strftime()` function, but I have no idea where in my Code to use it...

I tried it with this, but it doesn't do anything

```
void addBiereintrag(Biereintrag biereintrag) {

    // Get writable Access
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    // With this query im trying to find out if the Date given by biereintrag is already in the Database
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_BIER, new String[]{KEY_DATUM}, KEY_DATUM + "=?",
            new String[]{biereintrag.getDatum()}, null, null,
            null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    // if cursor == null, there is no entry for the Date, and the i put a new Entry
    if (cursor == null) {
        Log.d("test", "cursor ist null");
        values.put(KEY_DATUM, biereintrag.getDatum()); // Datum aus get.Datum() holen
        values.put(KEY_ANZAHL, biereintrag.getAnzahl()); // Anzahl zum Datum holen

        // close DB connection
        db.close();
    } else {
        values.put(KEY_DATUM, biereintrag.getDatum()); // Datum aus get.Datum() holen

        // If there is already a Entry, then Add the value of biereintrag.getAnzahl() to the Value written in the cursor
        values.put(KEY_ANZAHL, biereintrag.getAnzahl() + cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("KEY_ANZAHL")));
        // close DB connection
        db.close();
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to upadte/insert `values` into your database after `values.put()` to make changes into database as:

```
// if cursor == null, there is no entry for the Date, and the i put a new Entry
if (cursor == null) {
    Log.d("test", "cursor ist null");
    values.put(KEY_DATUM, biereintrag.getDatum()); // Datum aus get.Datum() holen
    values.put(KEY_ANZAHL, biereintrag.getAnzahl()); // Anzahl zum Datum holen

    // insert values into database
    database.insert(TABLE_BIER, null, values);

    // close DB connection
    db.close();
} else {

    // If there is already a Entry, then Add the value of biereintrag.getAnzahl() to the Value written in the cursor
    values.put(KEY_ANZAHL, biereintrag.getAnzahl() + cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("KEY_ANZAHL")));

    //update database with new value
    database.update(TABLE_BIER, values, KEY_DATUM + " = ?",
                new String[]{ biereintrag.getDatum()});

    // close DB connection
    db.close();
}
```